# Convert existing Spring application to Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I have configured and working Spring-based REST application, but now I'd like to convert it to Spring-Boot.

My application uses Spring-Data-JPA on top of JPA datasource with Hibernate provider:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("foo.bar.web.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepositoryConfig {

    // properties ommited

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(className);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("foo.bar.web.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
            put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        }});
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

My REST endpoints implemented using SpringMVC with following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("foo.bar.web.controller")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

Web initializer:

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{
                ApplicationConfig.class,
                RepositoryConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to use Spring-Boot auto configuration because I'd like to reuse my existing configuration classes with minimal changes, but I cannot find correct way to do this. I tried to implement Spring-boot application class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, but I'm not 100% sure that my config classes is used, because in this case I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba21071f cannot be cast to javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`.

Also I tried throw away @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation from application class and add `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean to my context manually, but in this case the embedded tomcat is not configured properly.

It would be great if somebody can give me a hint how to solve my problem. I believe that all I need to do is somehow replace my WebInitilizer with Spring-Boot config.

Comment: I would suggest to use the auto config features as that would allow you to basically ditch most of your configuration or put in in the `application.properties`. And the best maintainable code is code not written.

Comment: I totally agree with you that auto config is a good feature, but this is my educational project and I think that manual configuration is more usefull for understanding how all these features works and how they are related to "traditional SpringMVC"

Comment: So you basically don't want to use Spring Boot or at least are working hard to use as little as possible of it. But if you really must just ditch your `WebInitializer` and replace it with one extending the `SpringBootServletInitializer` class instead.

Comment: Partially you are right. The only one purpose why I'd like to include Spring-Boot in my project is that fact that I need my app packaged to executable jar with embedded servlet container. And now after spending some time on research I'm working on replacing of my `WebInitializer` with `SpringBootServletInitializer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After spending a day in a research, I finally found a solition of my problem.
First of all I had to modify my entityManagerFactory() and transactionManager() beans:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("foo.bar.web.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
            put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        }});
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Also I totally removed my `WebInitializer`class and removed `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from `MvcConfig`. In Spring-Boot it's not possible to have class extended from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in classpath because if Spring-Boot find it, all automatic configuration related to SpringMVC will be skipped. Here is the final version of my `MvcConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("foo.bar.web.controller")
public class MvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

I used the version of Spring-Boot application class which shown in doc:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MultipartAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Note, that in my case I had to exclude `MultipartAutoConfiguration` from auto configuration because I've already have this feature configured in `MvcConfig`. Bun it is also possible to leave it autoconfigured, but in this case I had to tune allowed file size in application.properties config file or add a MultipartConfigElement bean to my classpath.